# Adding a JScrollPane to JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jdialog

I have a working `JDialog` and now I want to add scroll bars to it. The documentation is a bit confusing to me. Do I add the dialog to the `JScrollPane` or vice-versa?

It seems like all the examples have a `JPanel` in the dialog and the panel is scrollable. I have a dialog that grows dynamically so I want the dialog itself to be scrollable. Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Reply to Andrew Thompson**

Thanks for the reply.

I let the size be determined by the layout manager at this point. I'm not exactly sure yet how big to let it get yet so I have not set any sizes. It just grows as I add rows. That will be part of this development phase. The width will not change, just the height. I display the dialog using 'invokelater'. This is the relevant code:

```
timeLineDialog = new JDialog();
timeLineDialog.setLayout(layout);
timeLineDialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.MODELESS);
timeLineDialog.setTitle("Time Line Settings");
timeLineDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
.
.
.
timeLineDialog.pack();
timeLineDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(GUI.getInstance().getFrame());
timeLineDialog.setVisible(true);
```

[image]

I want the scroll bars on the right side of the dialog pane.

Comment: *"Do I add the JDialog to the JScrollPane or vice-versa?"* Neither. Instead add the main panel (the things that need to be scrolled) of the dialog to the scroll pane, then add the scroll pane to the dialog. *"I have a dialog that grows dynamically so I want the dialog itself to be scrollable."* I'm confused about what you mean. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used / where the scroll bars should appear.

Comment: I would highly recommend that you take the time to look at `JTable`

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. Unfortunately this thing evolved rather than was designed. I may decide to do a complete rewrite at some point but I need to get what I have working for now.

Comment: After experimenting with JTable I find that is is not suitable for my application. There are too many things that I cannot do with it. For example, I cannot span columns (without extensive code) and even if I implement that can't I have a non-scrolling header if takes 2 rows.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to create a JDialog, then add a JScrollPane to it and your content inside that. The following code worked for me:

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Dialog extends JDialog {
    private final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    //I added the breaks to the label below to be able to scroll down.
    private final JLabel lblContent = new JLabel("<html><body><p>Content<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Content<br><br><br><br><br><br>Content</p></body></html>");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
                    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Dialog() { 
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        scrollPane.setViewportView(lblContent);

    }
}
```

[image: How it looks]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense to me. What is now the JDialog should be changed to JScrollPane and then that added to the JDialog. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, thinking about this more, do I even need a JDialog? Would not a ScrollPane by itself work?

Comment: I think I have it figured out. You example worked because you added 1 component. I found out that you can only add one component to a JScollPane thus the JDialog needs to be added to the scroll pane as its single component. I need to do some work on this so I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: How about adding a JPanel and adding content to that? I think scrolling will work if the panel is bigger than the ScrollPane.

Comment: Well, I have a JDIalog already working. Is converting it to a JPanel a big deal?

Comment: I don't think so. Just try to add the Objects to the JPanel instead of the ContentPane and see how it turns out.